# I am trying to make an image filter which seems finished but the only thing is that whnen I load the page it is blank until I click on filter list

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that I GOT FROM W3SCHOOLS. It all works except for on the first pageload it gives me a blank page, but then after when I click on one of the subjects then it works.

````
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}```
````

Comment: Your code is not complete. Add your html code.

Comment: <div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('anim')"> Animations</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('typo')"> Typography</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('edito')"> Editorial Design</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('img')"> Images</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fashiondesign')">Fashion design</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('photo')"> Photography</button>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You didnt share html part of your code contains  but its guessable anyway. You can add show class to any of them you want to show on first load. For example `<div class="filterDiv typo show">...</div>` if you want show typo section on first load.

Comment: Hi, thanks! That worked, I just have to add it to all my divs and they show up and then they can be filtered, thanks a lot!!!